# Using recursive radix sort in parallel bucket sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, recursion, radix-sort

I'm trying to write a fast algorithm to sort a vector of a large amount of integers like:

`159 14 5 97 6 54`

so far, my program breaks the vector into small buckets by the MSD like:

```
bucket[1]:159 14
bucket[5]:5 54
bucket[6]:6
bucket[9]:97
```

and now I'm required to use recursive radix sort to sort the bucket in most significant digit order:

```
bucket[1]:14 159
bucket[5]:5 54
bucket[6]:6
bucket[9]:97
```

This is the recursive radix code I found online:

```
// Sort 'size' number of integers starting at 'input' according to the 'digit'th digit
// For the parameter 'digit', 0 denotes the least significant digit and increases as significance does
void radixSort(int* input, int size, int digit){
  if (size == 0)
    return;

  int[10] buckets;    // assuming decimal numbers

  // Sort the array in place while keeping track of bucket starting indices.
  // If bucket[i] is meant to be empty (no numbers with i at the specified digit),
  // then let bucket[i+1] = bucket[i]

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    radixSort(input + buckets[i], buckets[i+1] - buckets[i], digit+1);
  }
}
```

I don't know how to implement this bit into my code, I'm not sure about what bucket[] do in the code above. Can anyone explain what changes should I make? Here's the multithread code I'm using which is not performing well since I'm not using recursive.

```
void sort(unsigned int numCores, std::vector<unsigned int> numbersToSort){
// ******************Stage 1****************
// Use multithread to seperate numbers into buckets using the most significant digits
  auto smallbuckets = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>>>>();
  std::mutex mutex;

  unsigned int workload = numbersToSort.size() / numCores;

  std::function<void(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)> put_small_buckets;
  put_small_buckets = [this, &smallbuckets, &mutex]
(unsigned int id, unsigned int start, unsigned int end) {

    auto buckets = std::make_shared<std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>>>(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>>());
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        buckets->push_back(std::vector<unsigned int>());
    }

    for (unsigned int i = start; i < end; ++i) {
        unsigned int a = numbersToSort[i];
        std::string tmp = std::to_string(a);
        char c = tmp.at(0);
        int ia = c - '0';
        (*buckets)[ia].push_back(numbersToSort[i]);
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    smallbuckets.push_back(buckets);
  };

// create a container of threads
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> containerOfThreads;

// create threads and add them to the container.
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numCores; ++i) {
    // start the thread.
    unsigned int start = workload * i;
    unsigned int end = workload * (i + 1);
    if(i == numCores - 1) end = this->numbersToSort.size() ;
    containerOfThreads.push_back(std::make_shared<std::thread>(put_small_buckets, i, start, end));
  }

// join all the threads back together.
  for (auto t : containerOfThreads) t->join();

  numbersToSort.clear();
// ******************Stage 2****************
// Put small multithreaded buckets back to the bucket of radix(10)

  auto bigbuckets = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>>();
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
    bigbuckets.push_back(std::make_shared<std::vector<unsigned int>>(std::vector<unsigned int>()));
  }

int current_index = 10;

std::function<void()> collect;
collect = [this, &smallbuckets, &current_index, &mutex, &collect, &bigbuckets] () {
    mutex.lock();
    int index = --current_index;
    mutex.unlock();
    if (index < 0) return;
    auto mybucket = bigbuckets[index];
    for (auto i = smallbuckets.begin(); i != smallbuckets.end(); ++i) {
        mybucket->insert(mybucket->end(), (*(*i))[index].begin(), (*(*i))[index].end());
    }
    collect();
  };

// create a container of threads
  containerOfThreads.clear();

// create threads and add them to the container.
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numCores; ++i) {
    containerOfThreads.push_back(std::make_shared<std::thread>(collect));
  }

// join all the threads back together.
  for (auto t : containerOfThreads) t->join();

// ******************Stage 3****************
// Sort big buckets

  for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
    bigbuckets.push_back(std::make_shared<std::vector<unsigned int>>(std::vector<unsigned int>()));
  }
  std::function<void(unsigned int, unsigned int)> sort_big_buckets;
  sort_big_buckets = [this, &bigbuckets, &mutex]
  (unsigned int start, unsigned int end) {
    unsigned int curr = start;
    while(curr < end){

        auto mybucket = bigbuckets[curr];
        std::sort(mybucket->begin(),mybucket->end(), [](const unsigned int& x, const unsigned int& y){
            std::string tmp1 = std::to_string(x);
            std::string tmp2 = std::to_string(y);
            return lexicographical_compare(tmp1.begin(), tmp1.end(), tmp2.begin(), tmp2.end());
            //return aLessB(x,y,0);
        } );
        ++curr;
    }
  };
// create a container of threads
  containerOfThreads.clear();

  workload = 10 / numCores;
// create threads and add them to the container.
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numCores; ++i) {
    // start the thread.
    unsigned int start = workload * i;
    unsigned int end = workload * (i + 1);
    if(i == numCores - 1) end = 10 ;
    containerOfThreads.push_back(std::make_shared<std::thread>(sort_big_buckets, start, end));
  }

// join all the threads back together.
  for (auto t : containerOfThreads) t->join();
// put all elements back to numbersToSort
  for (auto i = bigbuckets.begin(); i != bigbuckets.end(); ++i) {
    numbersToSort.insert(numbersToSort.end(), (*i)->begin(), (*i)->end());
  }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why have a vector (I assume) of shared pointers to `std::thread`? Are you passing that vector around? Will you do more with the threads than just join them? Why not just a simple vector of `std::thread` objects? Then you could use `emplace_back` to create the threads.

Comment: As for your problem, what is `bigbuckets`? What is the contents of `bigbuckets`? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not passing the vector around and I'm using it because one of my textbook example is using it. I'll try the method you mentioned, thank you for the advice! Also I've edited the example with what I've done trying to approach the sorting.

Comment: Do you really want to sort integers in lexicographical order of there string representation? Meanwhile, your code does not do well because you use to_string for every comparision, bucketing and do zillions of other temporary memory allocations. If you really want that order, you better transform all integers to strings beforehand, and make 11 buckets per digit position putting numbers that are not long enough into additional bucket.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin Yes I do want them in most significant digit order which is pretty much lexicographical order. Can you explain what you mean by numbers that are not long enough?

Comment: Comparision of full strings is excessive for radix sort. You only need to check 1 digit per bucketing on each digit deepness. But if string "1" goes into bucketing of level 1, you should not access its 2nd (index 1) digit. Instead you should check string length and put numbers shorter than current level aside. Such numbers form another bucket, it needs no further sorting, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know how to implement this bit into my code, I'm not sure about what bucket[] do in the code above. Can anyone explain what changes should I make?

To be honest, buckets[] is not needed. The idea is to keep indexes of bucket beginnings here, but since later buckets are processed in the same order one by one, it's possible to use a couple of additional variables instead of this array.

As I've said, you should convert numbers to strings and sort strings. This way you'll be able to check 1 character per bucketing, not doing all create-string->compare->destroy-string operations. In the end you'll have to convert strings back to numbers.

The part of code you were asking can look like this:

```
void radixSort(std::vector<std::string>::iterator begin, std::vector<std::string>::iterator end, int digit){
    if (begin == end)
        return;

    // first skip short numbers
    e = begin;
    for (auto p = begin; p != end; ++p)
        if (p->size() <= digit)
        {
            if (p != e)
                std::swap(*p, *e);
            q++;
        }
    if (e == end)
        return;

    for (char d = '0'; d <= '9'; ++d)
    {
        auto s = e;
        for (auto p = e; p != end; ++p)
            if (p->at(digit) == d)
            {
                if (p != e)
                    std::swap(*p, *e);
                e++;
            }
        radixSort(s, e, digit+1);
    }
}
```

To sort string vector you can do something like this:

```
radixSort(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```